# How to set Button BackgroundImage if empty in wpf

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

i am very new to wpf, and i am familiar with WinForm in vb.net but now i want learn wpf which i set Project to use wpf but in vb.net i use this:

```
' checking if there is no background image in the button1
If IsNothing(butt1.BackgroundImage) Then
' then button1 appears
butt1.Visible = True
'and assign button2 background image to button1 background image since it is empty.
butt1.BackgroundImage = butt2.BackgroundImage
'assigning button2 background image to be empty
butt2.BackgroundImage = Nothing
'hiding button2
butt2.Visible = False
```

so i design buttons using xaml but i want use this code in button1 click event, i also realized everything seems to be different in wpf, i hope some one helps me achieve this in wpf.
Thank you

Comment: this is so different from wpf that i guess you might not use it in any way
check out some totourials and you will soon see that wpf offers way more elegant ways to solve your issues with a lot less code like this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WPF, the `Button` has a `Content` property that you can set to a `string` or any element including an `Image`:

```
button1.Content = new Image { Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/pic.png", UriKind.Relative)), Stretch = Stretch.Fill };
```

There is no concept of a "background" image.

The [Stretch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.stretch?view=netframework-4.7.2) property of the `BitmapImage` describes how content is resized to fill its allocated space.